# Placing a textarea and a form to the bottom of the div distorts the width of the textarea

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place a textarea and a form with input type submit to the bottom of the page. My challenge is that I can place the both to the bottom of the page but the width of the textarea gets distorted. This is my code:

```css
.msg_input {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid white;
  border-top: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Safari/Chrome, other WebKit */
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  /* Firefox, other Gecko */
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.goBottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="goBottom">
  <textarea placeholder="...type here" class="msg_input" rows="4">
  </textarea>

  <form method="post" action="/logout">
    <input class="btn btn-link" type="submit" value="Exit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

the width of the textarea is not taking the full width 100% of the page. Please what could be wrong?

Comment: try adding `left:0` and `right: 0` to `.goBottom`.

Comment: wonderful....... post this as an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update the following css:

```
.goBottom{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Reason this should work:
The fixed position element doesn't seem to take full width. Hence this makes sure that it is. textarea takes full width of goBottom element.